# dustjs-linkedin with express 3

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, dust.js

I am trying to get `dustjs-linkedin` working with an express 3 project, however I can't seem to get past this error:

```
Error: Template name parameter cannot be undefined when calling dust.compile
at Object.compiler.compile (/home/user/project/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler.js:21:16)
at Object.dust.compileFn (/home/user/project/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/lib/dust.js:109:37)
at Function.exports.dust.render (/home/user/project/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:226:56)
at /home/user/project/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:146:25
at /home/user/project/node_modules/consolidate/lib/consolidate.js:99:5
at fs.js:266:14
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

I can reproduce this with a brand new express 3 project like so:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// added these 3
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');
var cons = require('consolidate');
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// added this 1
app.set('view engine', 'dust');

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**package.js**

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.7",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "*",
    "consolidate": "*"
  }
}
```

**routes/index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
```

**views/index.dust**

```
Title: {title}
```

The strange thing is, I have a project using express 3 and `dustjs-linkedin` that is working just fine. I ran a diff on the files in the `dustjs-linkedin` module and the working version has a lot of files in `dist` while the project throwing the error only has a few, namely:

**working**/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/dist:

```
dust-core.js  dust-core.min.js  dust-full.js  dust-full.min.js  LICENSE
```

**workingProject**/node_modules/dustjs-linkedin/dist:

```
dust-core-1.1.1.js      dust-core-2.0.0.min.js  dust-full-1.2.0.js      dust-full-2.0.1.js
dust-core-1.2.0.js      dust-core-2.0.1.js      dust-full-1.2.1.js      dust-full-2.0.2.js
dust-core-1.2.1.js      dust-core-2.0.2.js      dust-full-1.2.2.js      dust-full-2.0.3.js
dust-core-1.2.2.js      dust-core-2.0.3.js      dust-full-1.2.2.min.js  dust-full-2.1.0.js
dust-core-1.2.2.min.js  dust-core-2.1.0.js      dust-full-1.2.3.js      dust-full-2.2.0.js
dust-core-1.2.3.js      dust-core-2.2.0.js      dust-full-1.2.3.min.js  dust-full-2.2.2.js
dust-core-1.2.3.min.js  dust-core-2.2.2.js      dust-full-1.2.4.js      dust-full-2.2.2.min.js
dust-core-1.2.4.js      dust-core-2.2.2.min.js  dust-full-1.2.5.js      dust-full-2.2.3.js
dust-core-1.2.5.js      dust-core-2.2.3.js      dust-full-1.2.6.js      dust-full-2.2.3.min.js
dust-core-1.2.6.js      dust-core-2.2.3.min.js  dust-full-2.0.0.js
dust-core-2.0.0.js      dust-full-1.1.1.js      dust-full-2.0.0.min.js
```

This demo of a 'working' project gives me the same error:
https://github.com/chovy/express-template-demo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Edit]**

An issue is discussed here:

https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/commit/e5ebff0f7b32f8ff0883be7f7924507b314eef1d

In `[/node_modules/]consolidate/lib/consolidate.js` go to `exports.dust.render` function:

```
...
try {
  var tmpl = cache(options) || cache(options, engine.compileFn(str));
  tmpl(options, fn);
} catch (err) {
  fn(err);
}
...
```

`engine.compileFn` is called sending `str` as parameter, `str` is actually the template itself:

```
Title: {title}
```

`engine.compileFn` is `compiler.compile(source, name)` in `[/node_modules/]dustjs-linkedin/lib/compiler.js`.

`source` is template sent, however `name` which is the template name and should be `index` in our case, is never set (**undefined**).

Alternatively, I prefer to use Payapl's Adaro library for `express 3.x` and `linkedin-dustjs`. It's part of their project [kraken.js](http://krakenjs.com/), but can be used as a standalone dust wrapper for express:

https://github.com/paypal/adaro

As mentioned in README.md:

```
var express = require('express');
var dustjs = require('adaro');

var app = express();

app.engine('dust', dustjs.dust({});
app.set('view engine', 'dust');

// For rendering precompiled templates:
// app.engine('js', dustjs.js({ ... ));
// app.set('view engine', 'js');
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `adaro` and it does in fact make things work, but I would still like to know why just the raw `linkedin` version is throwing this error.