# Can't find module 'dust'

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to use Dustjs with Express but encountering a problem. Here my code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
  , cons = require('consolidate')
  , app = express();


app.engine('html', cons.dust);
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home', { name: 'Tom' });
})

app.listen(4000);
```

and dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.x",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "consolidate": "*",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "*",
    "dustjs-helpers": "*"
  },
```

When I run the code, an error message showed up

```
Error: Cannot find module 'dust'
```

I don't get it. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you run `npm i dust`?

Comment: I find that dustjs is Linkedln fork of Dust. So I thought I wouldn't need to install dust, just dustjs-linkedin and dustjs-helpers are enough. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original `dust` module have been deprecated, and consolidate does not support `dustjs-linkedin`.
A suggestion is to use [Adaro](https://github.com/krakenjs/adaro), created by PayPal for [KrakenJS](http://krakenjs.com/).

Sample code:

```
var dustjs = require('adaro');    
var app = express();

app.engine('dust', dustjs.dust({});
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
```

*with info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218008/2083599)*

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. Another question, I don't want the template's extension is ".dust" by default. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: Just change the call to `app.engine` to use what you want. See [here](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.engine) for reference

Comment: I changed it to `app.engine('html', dustjs.dust({}))`, but the message showed up again.

Comment: Seems like `view engine` is the default engine to use when your call to `res.render()` misses the extension. So you'll have to set it to html as well ([ref](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app-settings))

Comment: I changed that as well but another error:

`Error: ENOENT, open '/home/abc/Dropbox/Express/webapp/app/views/home.dust'`

It seems like it still looks up the .dust file